# PHP Soapclient modify Envelope

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

We are currently working in a **PHP & SOAP** integration. With 6 other requests, all our code is working great because our evelope is the same, but we are having problems with our last request, wich have its evelope different than others.

Normal envelope (6 other one):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xxx.ws.xxx.com/">
```

New envelope (last request):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.ws.xxx.com/">
```

We have tried using **SoapVar** and **SoapParam** classes to change the envelope, but we currently have not got any progress. ¿How can we do it?

Furthermore, we also need in this new request to change some other parameters:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns2="http://xxx.ws.xxx.com/">
                               <soap:Body>
                                  <PackagePre xmlns="http://xxx.ws.xxx.com/">
                                     <PreBookRQ locale="es_ES" xmlns="">
                                        <Authentication user="XXX" password="XXX"/>
                                        <Booking>
                                           <ProductList xsi:type="ns2:myproduct" address="null 0" categoryCode="CAT34"...
```

So we need to:

- Change envelope.
- Add Packagepre xmlns (same as ns1 in envelope).
- ProductList: add xsi:type="ns2:myproduct"

Any help is welcome :-).

Regards.